# Buying UK train ticket with foreign debit card

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, payment-cards

I want to purchase a UK train ticket, but I have no credit card. All I have is a debit card from The Netherlands, since that's where I live. I've been scouring the Internet for 2 days but every site rquires a Credit Card or UK Debit Card.

Is it possible at all to buy a ticket online with a foreign debit card?

Comment: How about PayPal? This site indicates they accept that though still need a card to validate when you pick up the tickets. http://ehelp.thetrainline.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4085/kw/Paypal have you explored that option already?

Comment: "All National Rail train companies accept the major cards such as Visa, Visa Delta, MasterCard, Maestro and Amex.  Some train companies also accept Diners Club International, Solo and Electron."

Comment: Durect debit is not the same as a debit card. I'm not aware of any sites that care about where your debit card is from as long as it is visa or maestro

Comment: @CMaster I don't know about the Netherlands but a normal German Maestro is not accepted because those are not set-up for internet payments. Might or might not be also the case here.

Comment: What about [loco2](http://help.loco2.com/article/497-what-payment-methods-do-you-accept)? It claims to accept Maestro.

Comment: Dutch bank cards (debit) can not be used for online buys.  I am Dutch and have tried to use my card at times, never been accepted.

Answer (score 4):

There is a travel agency in the Netherlands who specialize in train travel, [de Treinreiswinkel,](http://www.treinreiswinkel.nl/) and who will get you UK train tickets, as far as I know also at the special low cost early booking fees.
You do pay for the service, so you do need enough of a win on the cost of the tickets to make it work.

Your Dutch bank card is likely enough to get tickets out of the machines in the UK, most are, check with your bank whether yours is restricted to only Dutch use, (unlikely but possible) but non of the bank cards (debit cards) can be used for online or foreign buys.

If you buy your tickets using someone elses credit card, you should have that particular card with you when you collect the tickets. If possible, have the tickets send to your house.
When stuck, try any card with a magnet strip even a library card can do if it has a strip.
Or go to the ticket window and ask for the ticket there, explaining that you do not have the card on hand, (tell the truth if asked but you may leave it vague if not asked,) and give them the print out of the ticket confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

[Trainline](https://www.thetrainline.com/) accepts PayPal and MasterPass, both of those companies have an active presence in the Netherlands:

https://www.paypal.com/nl/

https://masterpass.com/#en-nl/

so you should be able to use them to pay Trainline with your debit card (or bank account - thanks @Willeke).

Comment: In case of Paypal, you may not be able to pay by debit card but it should be possible to set up a direct payment from your bank account, I had mine connected to my credit card but have added my bank account since.